# Compile error no line highlighted

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a compile error: expected expression. No line is highlighted XD

```
Sub name()

Dim arr() As String
Dim lastRow As Long
c = 2

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        arr = Split(.Cells(i, 1), " ")

        For Each e In arr
            .Cells(i, c).Value = arr(e)
            c = c + 1
        Next

        Set arr = Empty

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(i, c).Value = arr(e)` E is a string variable not a integer try `.Cells(i, c).Value = e`

Comment: I think its the name of your procedure.

Comment: LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL YEP Edit: post answer?

Comment: You will want to put c=2 inside the loop or it will not restart on column B each row iteration.

Comment: @ScottCraner lol yep. Literally just did that. BUUUTTTT, code still needs tweaking :/ Trying to pull names XD Will put in more effort on my part before I ask for more help <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gtwebb stated the name was the main issue.

There were a couple other minor thing I found will debugging:

```
Sub name2()

Dim e As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim c As Integer
Dim arr() As String
c = 2

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        c = 2
        arr = Split(.Cells(i, 1), " ")

        For Each e In arr
            .Cells(i, c).Value = e
            c = c + 1
        Next

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a new question. 8)

Comment: An example please. @findwindow

Comment: code needed more work then just a new name, just work it into your answer and this can be a complete (accepted) answer

Comment: is there anything that would help delineate between name and not name.

Comment: @gtwebb **CLASSY**

Comment: What about the first letter of the word, is it capitalized versus not?

Comment: See picture above in OP please. Edit: uh, it won't always be `side`. Could be `party`, `friend`...

Comment: Ok, Does the word `Side` always precede the name?

Comment: You are asking a computer to think.  Is the list short of possible preceding words?

Comment: Oooooooo, I can build an array of preceding words eh?! GENIUS. Edit: you're correct. There's maybe 6? possibilities.

Comment: There you go make an array then when those words are found you start your mining of the names.  If you get stuck feel free to ask another question :P

Comment: What, you think I couldn't come up with a formula answer?

Comment: @ScottCraner So I figured it out with vba. But ok, do it with a formula. And you can't use `substitute`, `index`, `match`,`mid`,`left`,`right`,`len` and any other function that includes a vowel =P Edit: there are actually only 3 key words. `party`,`side` and `friends`. Edit2: some names only have a first name. So I expect this in 3 minutes. GO

Comment: @ScottCraner It's been way over 3 minutes.

Comment: @jeeped wanna give this a shot? Or is Scott trolling me XD

Comment: @findwindow you tied my hands so I did not think you were serious.

Comment: oooooohhhh lolololol that part was a joke XD Edit: I should ask a new question. You definitely deserve points if you do it with formulas.

Comment: @findwindow `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),IFERROR(SEARCH("Friends",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99))),IFERROR(SEARCH("Side",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99))),SEARCH("party",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))))+COLUMN(A:A)*99,99))` :P  Copy accros and down as far as needed.

Comment: Gah. It's the same thing you did yesterday XD

Comment: I mean, I should have known better. I clearly didn't _learn_ anything -_-