# Index/Match with Min (or equivalent)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to return a value based on the MIN() in a range.  Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6V4s.jpg), but here's the data:

```
Category        Types       pts      Policeman       Hero
Jurisdiction    City        -10         x   
                State         0     
                Country      20                       x
Vehicle         Car          -2         x   
                Bus          20     
                Unicycle     20                       x
Sidekick        No Sidekick -20         x   
                One           5     
                Multiple     10                       x
Powers          None        -30                       x
                Super        2          x
                Kenny        30
```

My goal is for each "person" (Policeman and Hero), look in their column, and return the value from column B, where there's an X by the "minimum" value.

In other words, for "Policeman", the min. value with an 'X' is "No Sidekick", so I want my Index/Match to return that.  For "Hero", the minimum value with an "X" is "None" (under "Powers").

I've tried:
`=Index(B2:B13,Match(Index(Min(C2:C13),Match("x",D2:D13,0))&"x",C2:C13&D2:D13,0))` but it doesn't work.

I've also tried 
`=Index(B2:B13,Min(If(D2:D13="x"),Row(D2:D13)-1))`

I can see the formula in my mind, just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Thanks for any ideas/help.

(I don't have to use Index/Match, so if there's another way (`Sumproduct()` perhaps?), I'm open to it!)

Comment: Batman, who taught me index/match, is now asking about it??? Downvoted and flagged.

Comment: Why do I need to recreate your data to test my formula? :P.  Get your data where I can copy/paste and I am sure someone will get you the formula.

Comment: lol "someone" like there's a question to who it might be XD

Comment: @ScottCraner - Done. Now we can let that someone know :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do it(Untested):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MATCH(1,INDEX((D$2:D$13="x")*($C$2:$C$13=AGGREGATE(15,6,$C$2:$C$13/(D$2:D$13="x"),1)),),0))
```

---

Only because it is Bruce.

I merged the column D and E and so forth, and yes I know I did the cardinal sin in merging but hey, I figure you can do what you want. I am just showing a concept:

[image]

In D14:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$C$2:$C$13/(D$2:D$13="x"),ROW(1:1))
```

Then in E14:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$2:$C$13)-1)/((D$2:D$13="x")*($C$2:$C$13=D14)),COUNTIF(D$14:D14,D14)))
```

Then copy down and over

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick!  Would you mind explaining the `Aggregate()` part? This is a pretty clever formula!  Also, if I wanted to get the "MAX" number, do I just change part of the `Aggregate` formula to `14` instead of `15`?, or would that require something completely different?

Comment: Nope, just change the `15` to `14` and it should work.  The first part as you know denotes the type of formula,  The `6` says to ignore errors. We want this because we are actually going to force some errors.  The third part, We put the column in which we want to find the MIN or MAX and divide it by a Boolean expression which will return a 1 or 0.  When it is false it is 0 and returns an error because you can't divide by 0.  Then the last tells us we want the 1 st largest of smallest.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!  (I know this is outside the scope of my original question - but if there's a case where I have two values equal, is there a formula that would return *both*? IE: If above, say "Hero" has -10 for Car and -10 for No Sidekick.  ...I have a feeling that's ***way*** outside the scope and would be a new question altogether, if not requiring VBA, so just let me know). Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: It would be more difficult and would require a helper column.

Comment: `Only because it is Bruce.` wow ok. I am gonna go cry in corner now ;_;

Comment: @findwindow as if I haven't stretched the rules for you too. :P

Comment: link =P I don't recall any =PP

Comment: @findwindow did not need to search far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756773/compile-error-no-line-highlighted 8P

Answer (score 3):

One answer using index/match would be

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(MIN(IF($C$2:$C$15="x",$B$2:$B$15,9999)),IF($C$2:$C$15="x",$B$2:$B$15,""),0))
```

columns are wrong since I used my own data but the concept works.

Comment: Ah, you're using `9999` because we want min.